# 504 request timeout Nginx proxy_pass to AWS ALB private subnet after a week

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

Currently I have 2 api servers on private subnet and route it to a ALB.
My Web application on public subnet I config nginx proxy to call api as below:

```
  location /api  {
    proxy_pass $my-alb-address
  }
```

At first it works like a charm. However after 2 week it has 504 error. When I on the web server I can "curl" directly to my ALB but not through my nginx proxy_pass and it error as 504:

After I restart the nginx it seems to work again. But after 2 week again The error still happens.

I dont know why. I think that I should create new VPC link to my ALB and call directly to it but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALB [doesn't have a static IP address](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-ip):

> The IP addresses for Classic Load Balancers and Application Load Balancers change over time. Don't use this information to statically configure your applications to point to these IP addresses.

In theory, when it changes, it's announced in advance and the old one is supposed to work until its TTL on the DNS entry expires. Nginx is supposed to [grace these settings](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

However, it might be that something doesn't work in this mix. In this case, Nginx will try to connect to the old IP address of the ALB, which is likely to produce the 504 (HTTP Gateway Timeout) error you're seeing. This also explains how the restart fixes it.

You can put an NLB in front of the ALB. NLB does have a static IP address.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked perfectly

Comment: I have one more question. I point DNS to ALB and proxy through that but problem still occur. Changing ALB to NLB is only solutions ?

Comment: @ĐứcMinh: that's a great follow-up question. Ask it!